# Rstudio opens all files in package after build

Tags: r, rstudio

Every time I build my package after a modification, R studio will display every file in the package as untitled, and I have to close them and reopen them in order to modify files before another build. To be honest, it doesn't affect functionality that much, but is annoying and can sometimes cause Rstudio to crash. 
Has anyone seen this before, and can suggest a fix? 
I would post a screenshot, but I am new to stackoverflow and don't have enough reputation (10).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured out what caused the problem, but I was able to solve it by deleting all the project files produced by Rstudio (.RProj.user, packagename.Rproj, .Rhistory, .Rbuildignore), and then creating a new project in the existing directory.